# Border not applied to merged cells but only to first cell

Tags: excel

I am trying to merge 2 cells and apply border style around it. The merge is working fine as expected , but the border is getting applied only to first cell.
Here is my code snippet. Could anyone help me out (Note: This is not complete code. At high level, i am creating a style, applying to cells and then merging the cells.
After applying color, the borders were not visible. so i added setBorder.. code to make it visible. But it is getting applied to only the first cell of the merged cell.

```
CellStyle newStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
cellStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
cellStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
cellStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
cellStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(i, i, 0, 19));
```

Comment: You should apply the border to the range of cells, not just the first cell.  For example, if you merge `A1` and `B1`, you should use `Range("A1:B1").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous`

Comment: I would also suggest you merge the cells **before** you apply the CellStyle.